# Dual database for Java Spring Integration JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, quartz-scheduler

Currently I'm using H2 database for Junit integration testing with Spring Data, its working fine but I configured one more database with Junit test. But now it doesn't work. Please help me to resolve this.

I try to configure the additional database for quartz schedulers.

Comment: Hi guys,
Im getting below error while using quartz database with junit integration testing

"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/smc/config/QuartzConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Table "QRTZ_TRIGGERS" not found; "

Help me relove this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Error you posted means that there are no quartz-related tables in DB. And you are using it just for testing you may configure Quartz to use RAMJobStore for storing jobs.

See [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html).

In short, you have to set it in quartz configuration properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```